# Get JSON to HTML JavaScript table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I created a new category as the main table list table. the question is how to insert this JSON data into the JavaScript HTML table with the format below:

```
{
  query: {
    count: 10,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US",
    diagnostics: {},
    ...
  },
  test1: {
    count: 16,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US",
    diagnostics: {},
    ...
  },
  bold: {
    count: 1,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US",
    diagnostics: {},
    ...
  },
  home: {
    count: 1,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US",
    diagnostics: {},
    ...
  },
  .....
}
```

Table like this:

```
| Name | Count | Time | Language | Diag | 
------------------------------------------------------------- 
| query | 10 | 2015-12-09T17:12:09Z | en-US | 2 | 
| test1 | 16 | 2015-12-09T17:12:09Z | en-US | 2 | .....
```

Comment: Have you already tryed to code that?

Comment: You will have to generate HTML based on the json. This would require iterating over the json objects entries and creating html elements or markup. There is no magic function that will convert json to a html table.

Comment: in this case I need a javascript code that can define json data into the html table. so about what I described above

Comment: @borneo *"in this case I need a javascript code"*, SO requires a [mcve] which includes JavaScript. The JavaScript itself is not expected to work in fact it's expected  *not to work*, Nevertheless it's expected otherwise the OP (ie you) will appear as someone who is just demanding the work be done for you.

Comment: am sorry, ok, I understand what you are talking about besides I keep digging from several sites. so far I have only found from third parties from ZingGrid exmple xxx.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short example which can help you to understand the principle and then tune it to suit your needs.

```js
const source = {
  query: {
    count: 10,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US"
  },
  test1: {
    count: 16,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US"
  },
  bold: {
    count: 1,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US"
  },
  home: {
    count: 1,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US"
  }
}

const keys = Object.keys(source); // get the names properly
const colNames = Object.keys(source[keys[0]]); // get all column names

// Let's form table and header first
const table = document.createElement('table');
const header = document.createElement('tr');
header.innerHTML = `<th>name</th>`
header.innerHTML += colNames.map(name => `<th>${name}</th>`).join('');
table.appendChild(header);

// Now lets append all the rows
const rows = keys.map((key) => {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.innerHTML = `<td>${key}</td>`
  tr.innerHTML += colNames.map(name => `<td>${source[key][name]}</td>`).join('');
  return tr;
});

rows.forEach(r => table.appendChild(r));

// render
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
td, th {
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: how about if `const source` i replace with url?

Comment: Did you run the snippet? What exactly doesn’t work?

Comment: how about if const source i replace with url? exam from https://www.zpool.ca/api/currencies

Comment: Try to use `fetch()` to get data from url. After that just use the above code with received data.

Comment: i try `function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.zpool.ca/api/currencies',
            success: function() {}
        })
    }
    var data = getData;` but not work

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this?

This will generate html markup based on the JSON data. Then write it to the document.

```js
var data = {
  query: {
    count: 10,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US"
  },
  test1: {
    count: 16,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US",
  },
  bold: {
    count: 1,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US",
  },
  home: {
    count: 1,
    created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
    lang: "en-US",
  }
};

let htmlStr = "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Count</td><td>Time</td><td>Language</td></tr>";
const keys = Object.keys(data);
for (var key of keys) {
  let item = data[key];
  htmlStr += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${item.count}</td><td>${item.created}</td><td>${item.lang}</td></tr>`;
}
htmlStr += "</table>";
document.write(htmlStr);
```

```css
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: this work for me.. btw, how about `var data` replace as url (ajax)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a `<table>` in HTML, Apply some styles to it (see example below, you can run it)

Then run a loop on you data set and add rows to you table.

> Use string literals to replace data from you variable to rowHTML, or you can use any templating library to create a html template for cleaner code.

```js
var myData = {
 query: {
  count: 10,
  created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
  lang: "en-US",
  diagnostics: {},
 },
 test1: {
  count: 16,
  created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
  lang: "en-US",
  diagnostics: {},
 },
 bold: {
  count: 1,
  created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
  lang: "en-US",
  diagnostics: {},
 },
 home: {
  count: 1,
  created: "2015-12-09T17:12:09Z",
  lang: "en-US",
  diagnostics: {},
 }
};

var myDataKeys = Object.keys(myData);

var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");

for(var i=0; i<myDataKeys.length; i++) {
 const rowData = myData[myDataKeys[i]];
 const rowHTML = `<tr><td>${myDataKeys[i]}</td><td>${rowData.count}</td><td>${rowData.created}</td><td>${rowData.lang}</td>`;
 myTable.innerHTML += rowHTML;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
 <tr><td>Name</td><td>Count</td><td>Time</td><td>Language</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zac. i test but not work.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.zpool.ca/api/currencies',
            success: function(data) {
                let htmlStr = "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Count</td><td>Time</td><td>Language</td></tr>";
                const keys = Object.keys(data)
                for (var key of keys) {
                    let item = data[key];
                    htmlStr += `<tr><td>${key}</td><td>${item.algo}</td><td>${item.port}</td><td>${item.name}</td></tr>`;
                }
                htmlStr += "</table>";
                document.write(htmlStr);
            }
        });
```